# How to get another user's (including current user) followed sites

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, social, newsfeed, following

How to get another user's followed sites, programmatically.

It seems that `SPSocialFollowingManager followingManager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(userProfile, context);` only works for the current user; for another user it always returns null.

I have tried to run with elevated privileges and it can't get the result for even the current user.

Comment: Did you try this http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2013/08/13/get-followed-sites-for-an-user-in-sharepoint-2013-social/

Comment: yes, I had tried, but it didn't work.This is only get the current login user's followed sites, not a specific user. when I login as different user name, it retuned empty list.

Comment: Have you installed SP1? :)

Comment: I have SP1 installed and am noting the same behavior. I have also tried: impersonating via user tokens, temporarily nulling out HttpContext.Current, [rebuilding HttpContext.Current entirely](http://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Impersonation-in-SharePoint-2010-service-applications.aspx#.U6mowfldWSo), using a UserProfileManager [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee576331(v=office.15).aspx) that includes an ignore privacy flag, etc. I'm even unable to enumerate followed sites for all users using PowerShell or a console application, which is _weird_.

Comment: Also, apparently you _can_ get to another user's followed content via `UserProfile.FollowedContent`, but you cannot easily go from an array of `FollowedItem` objects to an array of `SPSocialActor` objects, as far as I know.

Comment: **Update:** I'm now able to enumerate followed sites for arbitrary users using a PowerShell script as well as a SharePoint console application. However, the same code used in the context of a non-null `HttpContext` (i.e. a web part) still returns an empty array. `GetFollowedCount()` returns `0` as well. Nulling out the `HttpContext` doesn't work either. For now, I'm refactoring in order to leverage the `FollowedItem` objects resulting from a call to `UserProfile.FollowedContent.GetItems()`. So lame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user's followed sites are stored within their personal site collection (i.e. their my site). By default, only the users themselves have access to their personal site collections (they are the primary site collection administrator). This is why the call to `SPSocialFollowingManager.GetFollowed()` isn't returning any `SPSocialActor` objects--the current user simply doesn't have access to the other user's personal site collection.

Depending on how your web applications are configured, elevating permissions may not be sufficient to resolve another user's followed sites because the application pool account under which the elevated code is running may not have access to the web application hosting the personal site collection of the user. Ultimately, SharePoint is doing the right thing here: security trimming the results of a list query based on the permissions of the current user.

*If you grant the application pool account that your code is running under Read access to the My Site Host web application* then you should be able to create an `SPSite` object representing the "non-current" user's personal site collection. With this `SPSite` object you can then new up an `SPServiceContext` and eventually call `SPSocialFollowingManager.GetFollowed()` in order to return the followed objects for that user. See [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for information on how to add a user policy to a web application (SharePoint 2013).

Okay, some code. In the snippet below, `userName` is the `LoginName` (i.e. account name) of the user whose followed sites we mean to get. This code is called from within a web part within a web application that *is not* configured as the My Site Host web application. However, the application pool account under which this code runs *has* been granted Read access to the My Site Host web application via Central Administration.

```
...

// get followed sites for a user that is not the current user
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    // resolve the user's profile
    UserProfile userProfile = null;

    using (var elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
    {
        var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(elevatedSite);
        var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
        if (userProfileManager.UserExists(userName))
        {
            userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(userName);
        }
    }

    if (userProfile != null)
    {
        // NOTE: for this to work properly the application pool account under which this code runs must have read permissions on the my site host web application

        // new up the user's personal site collection and get the user's followed sites            
        using (var personalSite = new SPSite(userProfile.PersonalSite.ID))
        {
            var personalServiceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(personalSite);
            // the next two lines are possibly redundant; these objects are recreated to ensure sanctity of context
            var personalUserProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(personalServiceContext);
            var personalUserProfile = personalUserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(userProfile.AccountName);
            var personalFollowingManager = new SPSocialFollowingManager(personalUserProfile, personalServiceContext);

            // if the user is following any sites, this array should not be empty
            var followedSites = personalFollowingManager.GetFollowed(SPSocialActorTypes.Sites);
        }
    }
});

...
```

No hacky nulling out or faking of `HttpContext.Current` necessary...

Comment: Can we get some feedback, @user29842? Please mark as answered or add additional follow up comments. Zombie questions hurt everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, @nsturdivant, it toatally resolved this problem. :)