# Getting list of followed sites for a specific user with Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, modern-experience, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

There is an undocumented API `/_vti_bin/homeapi.ashx/sites/followed` that returns the list of followed sites for the **currently logged in user**. This one does not seem to be useful due to permission-related limitations.

There is also a Graph API endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/Admin@Contoso.onmicrosoft.com/followedSites`

But it gives me access denied:
[image]

**PnP SharePoint PowerShell Script**

```
$AppSecret = 'XXXXX*[ZLq9Q3VFOwXGRm2NSP'
$appId = 'fb32c27b-XXXXX-4824-8af0-e8d303553d9e'
$AADDomain = 'contosoTenant.onmicrosoft.com'

Connect-PnPOnline -AppId $AppId -AppSecret $AppSecret -AADDomain $AADDomain
$accesstoken = Get-PnPAccessToken
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/Admin@contosoTenant.onmicrosoft.com/followedSites' -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accesstoken"} -Method Get
```

**Permissions assigned to the AAD App:**

[image]

**Question**

Is there a way to retrieve the list of followed sites for a specific user using REST API, Graph or some other way?

**Explanation**

We are going to need to write a crawler that runs every day and for every user in Office 365, gets the list of followed sites. This will later be used for a separate email notifications feature. But first, I am trying to understand if it's even possible to get users' followed sites.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**
There is a [similar question about SharePoint on-prem here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104462/how-to-get-another-users-including-current-user-followed-sites), but we are using Office 365, which makes this question different.

Comment: That other question is about sp 2013 this is SPO and Graph API, don't think this is duplicate.

Comment: Hey Denis. did my answer help u? thanks :9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look to the [Microsoft Graph API documentation, if you go to the "sites"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-follow?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) related v1.0 reference, you will notice you can perform a query like the one below:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/followedSites`

*Here is an example:*

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/5d0191d0-1165-4a89-fc96-3000081209fa/followedSites`

That query will return the followed sites for that target user, based **on its ID.**

*PS: for retrieving the sites followed by the current user, just query:*

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/followedSites`